# org-mode: how to input command

Tags: org-mode, emacs24

Just try org-mode and global todo list.

I tried the command: "C-c a t" as  press Ctrl+c, and immediate press a, and then t. But there is error.

When C-c a, there is a buffer, asking me to: 
select a attachment command (many options, but no 't').

[image]

Comment: You are pressing C-c C-a (Ctrl-C and Ctrl-a). Leave the Ctrl button after Ctrl-C. But I myself am facing problem in this. For me emacs says that C-c a is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Note that 'C-c a' and 'C-c C-a' are different keystrokes: C-c a t
means press c while holding Control down, then **release the Control key** and then press a and t. In particular, the attachment menu that you are getting is because you are invoking the org-attach command which is bound to C-c C-a.